# Sync SQL Binary column to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I’m attempting to use a piece of software (Layer2 Cloud Connector) to sync a local SQL table (Sage software) to a remote MySQL database where the data is used reports generated via the company's web app.  We are doing this with about 12 tables, and have been doing so for almost two years without any issues.

#### Background:

I’m using a simple piece of software the uses a SELECT statement to sync records from one table to another using ODBC.  In this case from SQL (SQLTable) to MySQL (MySQLTable). To do so, the software requires a SELECT statement for each table, a PK field, and, being ODBC-based, a provider.  For SQL I'm using the Actian Zen 4.5, and for MySQL I'm using the MySQL ODBC 5.3.

Here is a screenshot of what the setup screen looks like for each of the tables. I have omitted the other column names that I'm syncing to make the SELECT statement more readable.  The other columns are primarily varchar or int types.
[image: SQL table ODBC entity settings]

#### Problem

For unrelated reasons, we must now sync a new table. Like most of the other tables, it has a primary key column named rGUID of type binary.  When initially setting up the other tables, I tried to sync the primary key as a binary type to a MySQL binary column, but it failed when attempting to verify the SELECT statement on the SQLServer side with the error “*Cannot remove this column, because it is a part of the constraint Constraint1 on the table SQLTable*”.

Example of what I see for the the GUID/rGUID primary key values stored in the SQLTable via Access, or in MySQL after syncing as string:

- ¡狻➽䪏蚯㰛蓪
- Ҝ諺䖷ᦶ肸邅
- ब惈蠷䯧몰吲론�
- ॺ䀙㚪䄔麽骧⸍薉

To get around this, I use CAST in the SQLTable SELECT statement to CAST the binary value as a string using: `CAST(GUID as nchar(8)) as GUID`, and then set up the MySQL column as a VARCHAR(32) using utf8_general_ci collation.

This has worked great for every other table since we originally set this up.  But this additional table has considerably more records (about 120,000 versus 5,000-10,000), and though I’m able to sync 10,000 – 15,000 successfully, when I try to sync the entire table I get about 10-12 errors such as:

- *The metabase record 'd36d2dbe-fa89-4712-be4c-6b212367004b' is marked
  to be added. The table 'SQLTable' does not contain a corresponding
  row. Changes made to this metabase record will be reset to the
  initial state.*

**I don't understand what is causing the above error or how to work past it.**

#### What I’ve tried so far:

- I’ve confirmed the SQLTable has no other unique fields that could be
  used as PK in place of the rGUID column
- I’ve tried use different type, length and collation settings on the
  MySQL table, and have had mixed success, but ultimately still get
  errors when attempting to sync the entire table.
- I’ve also tried tweaking the CAST settings for the SQL SELECT
  statement, but nchar(8) seems to work best for the other tables
- I've tried syncing using `HASHBYTES('SHA1', GUID) as GUID` and syncing
  the value of that, but get the below ODBC error

[image: Hashbytes error]

I was thinking perhaps I could convert the SQL GUID to its value, then sync that as a varchar (or a binary), but my attempts at using CONVERT in the SQLTable SELECT statement have failed

Settings I used for all the other tables:
**SQL SELECT Statement**: `SELECT CAST(GUID as nchar(8)) as GUID, OtherColumns FROM SQLTable;`
**MYSQL SELECT Statement**: `SELECT GUID, OtherColumns FROM MySQLTable;`
**Primary Key Field**: GUID
**Primary Key Field Type**: String
**MySQL Column Type/Collation**: VARCHAR(32), utf8_general_ci

Any help or suggestions at all would be great.  I've been troubleshooting this in my spare time for a couple of weeks now, and have no had much success.  I'm not particularly familiar with the binary type, and am hoping someone might have an idea on how I might be able to successfully sync this SQL table to MySQL without these errors.

Comment: Are your GUIDs in SQL Server being stored as type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER or BINARY(16)?

Comment: @nnichols: Thank you for the reply. So far I've only interacted with the SQL tables via an Access connection, where they're shown as type  Binary in design view.

Comment: As you can connect with Access you should be able to connect with SSMS which will make your life easier.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I actually just installed it this morning as I'm more familiar with that than Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the small size of the datasets involved I would select as CHAR(36) from SQL Server and store in a CHAR(36) in MySQL.

If you are able to control the way the data is inserted by Layer2 Cloud Connector then you could set your MySQLTable GUID column as BINARY(16) -

- SELECT CAST(GUID AS CHAR(36)) AS GUID, OtherColumns FROM SQLTable;
- INSERT INTO MySQLTable (GUID) VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(GUID)))
- SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(GUID) AS GUID, OtherColumns FROM MySQLTable;

Comment: Thank you also for this reply.  I can give this a try right now - but wanted to add that the INSERT statement is obfuscated by the software, and not something I can customize/control.

Comment: In that case stick with selecting as CHAR(36) - `SELECT CAST(GUID as CHAR(36)) AS GUID, OtherColumns FROM SQLTable;` and set the MySQL column to CHAR(36)

Comment: Ok - for the MySQL SELECT, should I still use BIN_TO_UUID, or just select the GUID without any transformation?

Comment: No, just `SELECT GUID, OtherColumns FROM MySQLTable;`. This way you will have the same 36 character string representation of the GUID from both sources.

Comment: Thank you again. So this did sync the entire table successfully, but I noticed that each time I run the sync tool, it states that it's updating all of the table's records, rather than just any records with changed data.  Do you think it's possible to solve this?  I only ask as the sync process takes almost 1.75 hours each time, and the tool syncs the table changes every 30 mins . . .

Comment: I am not sure as I could not find any decent documentation on your chosen tool. Do you have a link to any documentation explaining its sync process? I assume the other tables are faster to sync, just because they are significantly smaller.

Comment: Thank you for assisting.  Website: https://www.layer2solutions.com/products/layer2-cloud-connector, user doc: https://www.layer2solutions.com/docs/default-source/technical/documentation/layer2-cloud-connector-user-documentation.pdf

Comment: If you search that documentation for "Ignore Changes Within Target" it suggests this should speed things up as it only checks for changes in the source (SQL Server), not the target (MySQL). Assuming your are doing a one-way sync and no changes are being applied to the MySQL data, this should improve things. I suspect it will still be quite slow because of the way this tool works.

Comment: After checking that box for Ignore Changes Within Target", I get the following error.  I'm going to reach out to the developer of the utility, but wanted to ask if you had any thoughts on this.  Leaving that box unchecks still results in a successful sync: An error occurred while executing connection 'tblJrnlRow Sync': Cannot set column 'GUID'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column. -- it's referring to the MySQL GUID column, which is the table upon which I checked that box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249789/discussion-between-nnichols-and-b4thc4t).